# a problem for REST API to send parameter by method GET in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

json code:

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"message": "Loaded cate two",
"data": {
    "id": 1,
    "cte_two_title": "Computer",
    "cate_ones_id": 1,
    "cte_type": 2,
    "created_at": "2018-09-15T09:41:15.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-09-15T09:41:15.000Z"
    }
}
```

API interface code :

```
@GET("cate_twos.json")
Call<Catetwolist> getCatetwo(
        @Query("cateone_id") int cte_one);
```

Class Catetwolist :

```
public class Catetwolist {
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private ArrayList<CateTwo> cateTwos = null;

public ArrayList<CateTwo> getCateTwolist() {
    return cateTwos;
}

public void setCateTwolist(ArrayList<CateTwo> cateTwos) {
    this.cateTwos = cateTwos;
    }
}
```

Class CateTwo :

```
public class CateTwo {
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("cate_ones_id")
private int cate_ones_id;
@SerializedName("cte_two_title")
private String cte_two_title;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getCate_ones_id() {
    return cate_ones_id;
}

public void setCate_ones_id(int cate_ones_id) {
    this.cate_ones_id = cate_ones_id;
}

public String getCte_two_title() {
    return cte_two_title;
}

public void setCte_two_title(String cte_two_title) {
    this.cte_two_title = cte_two_title;
    }
}
```

my call enqueue code in main class :

```
public class ListOfCategory_Two extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecycleView_ListCateForm_two recycleView_listCateFormTwo;
private ArrayList<CateTwo> cateTwos;


//Retrofit Api Interface
private APIIinterface apiIinterface;

@BindView(R.id.recycler_list_of_cate) RecyclerView recycler_list_of_cate;
@BindView(R.id.viewCateOneInMain) ViewGroup viewCateOneInMain;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_two_category);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager_category = new 
    LinearLayoutManager(MyApplication.mContext, 
     LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recycler_list_of_cate.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager_category);
    recycler_list_of_cate.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    apiIinterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIIinterface.class);
    Call<Catetwolist> catetwo_Call = 
    apiIinterface.getCatetwo(MyApplication.Current_cate_id_one);

    catetwo_Call.enqueue(new Callback<Catetwolist>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Catetwolist> call, Response<Catetwolist> 
    response) {
            cateTwos = response.body().getCateTwolist();;
            recycleView_listCateFormTwo = new 
   RecycleView_ListCateForm_two(cateTwos);
            recycler_list_of_cate.setAdapter(recycleView_listCateFormTwo);
            recycleView_listCateFormTwo.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recycler_list_of_cate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //loadingView_CateTwo.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Catetwolist> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i("aaa",t.getMessage() + "");
        }
    });

}
```

**after a run, I have the error of Call.enqueue in onFailure function:**

This code works when I do not send a parameter, but I get into trouble when I send it to the interface.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 57 path $.data.

Comment: Because "data" contains json object not json array.

Comment: please edit code and post them

Comment: no different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Instead of writing this in `ArrayList<...>`:

```
public class Catetwolist {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<CateTwo> cateTwos = null;

    public ArrayList<CateTwo> getCateTwolist() {
        return cateTwos;
    }

    public void setCateTwolist(ArrayList<CateTwo> cateTwos) {
        this.cateTwos = cateTwos;
    }
}
```

Write it just a class as class extends Object:

```
public class Catetwolist {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private CateTwo cateTwos = null;

    public CateTwo getCateTwolist() {
        return cateTwos;
    }

    public void setCateTwolist(CateTwo cateTwos) {
        this.cateTwos = cateTwos;
    }
}
```

Try it, Hope it helps.

Comment: update my code when Instead  your code in main have the error for ArrayList

Comment: I'm use this http://www.androiddeft.com/2017/10/08/retrofit-android/ but this doesn't work sent parameter in the query with GET method

Comment: @T3RON After changing the code which I suggested, change: `private ArrayList<CateTwo> cateTwos;` in your activity to `private CateTwo cateTwos;`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you mapped your "data" section as an ArrayList in your POJO:

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private ArrayList<CateTwo> cateTwos = null;
```

The JSON provided does not match the POJO, and that's the exception you are getting. "Data" is an object not an array. The parser expects an Array but it gets an Object instead.

How do you solve this?
Option 1:
 Change your JSON to match that pojo, it should look like this:

```
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"message": "Loaded cate two",
"data": [{
    "id": 1,
    "cte_two_title": "Computer",
    "cate_ones_id": 1,
    "cte_type": 2,
    "created_at": "2018-09-15T09:41:15.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-09-15T09:41:15.000Z"
    }]
}
```

Option 2:
Change the POJO to match that JSON:

```
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private CateTwo cateTwo = null;
```

Hope that helps!